# Capture video with Poltergeist, PhantomJS and Capybara

Tags: selenium, capybara, phantomjs, headless, poltergeist

Is it possible to capture video with PhantomJS in combination with the gems Poltergeist, Capybara and Cucumber?

I have used the Headless gem previously, which put a video in a specific folder in case a scenario failed. If all went well, no video was stored.

Headless uses Xvfb and ffmpeg. Can ffmpeg also be used to provide the same functionality as shown here: https://github.com/leonid-shevtsov/headless/blob/master/lib/headless/video/video_recorder.rb

I basically need the same functionality, but I have no idea how to go about it. Any advice is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

This is a PhantomJS tutorial to record videos: http://mindthecode.com/recording-a-website-with-phantomjs-and-ffmpeg

Comment: While this is useful, it unfortunately doesn't do exactly what I needed back then. It appears that you can only use it to start "recording" at a predefined moment. What I actually needed was a capture of the whole test run. But thanks for providing this very good tutorial!

Comment: Link is 404, answer is dead.

Answer (score 1):

You can't capture video with PhantomJS, but I guess you could hook something up to take a screenshot on each step that Capybara takes (you'd need to dig into the code to do that though).

Comment: seems like someone already [successfully recorded video](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/phantomjs/wluVGGjhL90/oGBXqh7QP44J) with PhantomJS, but I don't have a clue how to use that knowledge in my case. Any ideas?