# Create video stream from html5 <canvas>

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a audio visualizer written in JS which draws on a `<canvas>` element.

Is it possible (without screen-capture) to turn that `<canvas>` into a (realtime) video stream? Perhaps somehow write it to a socket directly.

the JS uses THREE.js for rendering.

Preferrably I'd like to be able to run this on a webserver, it's probably not possible to do this without actually using a browser, but if it is, I'd be very happy to hear about it ;)

Comment: Yes it is possible with a long list a caveats, Resolution, CPU speed, video quality, bandwidth and more. On a high end machine with medium resolution and a good connection it is doable. On random client machines, its not going to happen for some time to come.

Comment: could you perhaps explain in an answer as to how to achieve this?

Comment: Github for webm encoding javascript utilities, and the javascript socket API for transmitting to server, and whatever your fav server is, buffer and retransmit to clients.

Comment: @Blindman67 did you also tried webRTC-experiments guys' [RecordRTC](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC/)? (I didn't...) sounds promising on the paper.

Comment: Yes webRTC is the best I know of with a MIT licence, and seems to have matured a lot over the past year. To heavy (code base) for my needs, but great cross browser support, As for performance, there is only so much blood that can be drawn from stone, its done correctly so you won't get anything faster, but you would have to work hard to make something slower. Browsers need to add Video and audio encoding in as native functions befor streaming is a viable all round solution. webRTC would be my choice if starting from scratch.

Comment: recordRTC (at least the example) seems to just record webcam video/audio, I however want to actually capture whatever is rendered on a canvas and turn that into a video stream. please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @xorinzor https://github.com/muaz-khan/RecordRTC/tree/master/Canvas-Recording

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the info from Blindman67 I've managed to figure out a way of achieving the desired result.

I will end up using PhantomJS and have it write images to a /dev/stdout (or other socket) and use ffmpeg to turn that into a videostream. (sort of as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16887214/capture-video-with-poltergeist-phantomjs-and-capybara))

I will also run a test using [Whammy](https://github.com/antimatter15/whammy) but as described in the github that might not produce the desired result; only 1 way to find out.

Edit: I will also try the suggestion from kaiido to use [WebRTC](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/RecordRTC/Canvas-Recording)